# Why isn't the tkinter button showing up on the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, turtle-graphics

I am making a game and the first thing on the screen is a button that says play game. But the button isn't showing up on the screen for some reason? The function play_sound_game is basically the rest of my code.

I have already tried removing turtle.mainloop() but that doesn't work either.

```
    import turtle
    import tkinter as tk
    import time
    import pygame

    screen = turtle.Screen()

    turtle.ht()
    screen.bgcolor("blue")
    turtle.color('deep pink')
    style = ('Courier', 80, 'italic')
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-318,176)
    turtle.pu
    turtle.write('RHYMING WORDS', font=style)
    turtle.hideturtle()


    turtle.mainloop()


    #Button for play game
    button_playgame = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Play Game", command=play_sound_game, font=('Arial', '65',"bold"), foreground = 'red')

    button_playgame.config(height = -1, width = 4)
    canvas.create_window(272, 88, window=button_playgame)
```

I didn't get any error messages.

Comment: You have not rendered the button ```(.pack, .grid, .place)```also...```height = -1```?

Comment: So what do I change

Comment: Can you please tell me what I have to replace in my code to make it work. That would really helpfull, and I know how Tkinter works

Comment: If you knew how Tkinter works then you wouldn't have this issue lol. Like my first comment suggests, you have to place the widget...but since you know how tkinter works...

Comment: your problem is `mainloop` which create main window and runs all time till you close window. If you want to add something then you have to do it before `mainloop():`

Comment: and you don't have to use `(.pack, .grid, .place)` to add widget to `Canvas`

Comment: I didn't say to remove `mainloop()`  because tkinter needs it - OP has to create button before `mainloop()`.

Comment: so I put mainloop() as the last line in that code

Comment: When I do that it gives me an error saying canvas is not defined

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: they don't need to call pack, place, or grid. They are adding the window to the canvas with create_window.

Comment: you have error but it is different problem - I already has working code for you. I have to only describe it in aswer.

Comment: What do I have to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: @furas please describe working code for me. I need it.

Comment: Look at and run https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654017/4180176 - this may help you

Answer (score 1):

`turtle` uses widget `Canvas` from module `tkinter`. To add button you have to get access to this canvas

```
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
```

and then you can use it in

```
tk.Button(canvas.master, ...)
```

and

```
canvas.create_window(...)
```

Because `turtle.mainloop()` runs all time till you close window so you have to create button before `mainloop()`

Working example.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def play_sound_game():
    pass

screen = turtle.Screen()

turtle.ht()
screen.bgcolor("blue")
turtle.color('deep pink')
style = ('Courier', 80, 'italic')
turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(-318,176)
turtle.pu
turtle.write('RHYMING WORDS', font=style)
turtle.hideturtle()

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

button_playgame = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Play Game", command=play_sound_game, font=('Arial', '65',"bold"), foreground='red')
#button_playgame.config(height=1, width=4)

canvas.create_window(272, 88, window=button_playgame)

turtle.mainloop()
```

On Linux

[image]

Comment: Also one more question. Is it possible to change the background color of the button?

Comment: yes, `background="blue"` or shorter `bg="blue"`. Using hex code (#RRGGBB) `bg="#FF00DD"`. Doc: [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: The button color stays at white

Comment: on Linux it changes color to blue. It is white only when mouse is over button (hover) - but button has other options to change it. If you use other system then Linux then maybe your system not let change it.

Comment: Yeah I am using mac so probably